# OAuth with custom oauth provider in MVC 4

Tags: oauth, asp.net-mvc-4, trello

I'm writing a simple web application in MVC 4, and I want to [OAuth with Trello](https://trello.com/docs/gettingstarted/oauth.html) so that I can ask a user to log-in with their trello details and then see some of their cards.

Can anyone provide information about creating a custom oauth provider to support non-out of the box oauth providers? From what I can see, I *think* I need to create a custom Oauth provider (subclass `IAuthenticationClient` and use that) - is that right?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for adding custom providers?

Answer (score 11):

Okay, I spent the 11 hours since my comment writing a custom oAuth class for SO. Tomorrow I get to do one of sales force. I'm not excited.

Here's what I did:

1. Create a DataContract class for your expected Json/Xml. I went ahead and implemented everything that SO returns, but if you're only doing authorization you can probably cut it down to an ID and DisplayName.
2. Create a class that extends OAuth2Client from DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients. Use the [DotNetOpenAuth GitHub page](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth) for examples. This is the longest, and most painful step, especially if your json serialization is rusty.
3. Open up `/App_Start/AuthConfig.cs` and enter `OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(new YourClass(Your, Initalization, Params), "The Name You Want to Show Up On Your oAuth Login Button", ExtraDataIfYouNeedIt;` somewhere in the `RegisterAuth()` section. I haven't established what the ExtraData param is for, but I didn't need it in my case. Hopefully you won't need it in yours.

Edit: Updated github link.

Comment: `ExtraData` is just an `IDictionary` object; you can use it for whatever you want. I used it to bind some CSS classes I wanted to access in a partial view when I was listing available providers. Nice work, BTW.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I haven't had chance to do this because I've been moved onto other issues, but I intend to look at it sometime soon, so I'll take a look at what you did and get back to you!

Comment: Old thread, but note well that the DotNetOpenAuth page has moved to: https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth